# Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Auth\\Access\\Response::authorize()

Tags: laravel, class, response

I'm trying to use `Response::authorize()` in ContactPolicy.php
but I got this error

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response::authorize()

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\models\User;
use App\Contact;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response;

class ContactPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;
    /**
     * Determine whether the user can permanently delete the contact.
     *
     * @param  \App\models\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Contact  $contact
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function forceDelete(User $user)
    {
        return $user->role === 'admin'
            ? Response::allow()
            : Response::authorize();
    }
}
```

I visit this website to check Response class [Illuminate/Auth/Access/Response.html](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Auth/Access/Response.html)

then I checked file in my project `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response.php`
in my files I didn't find it ... all i find is this

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Auth\Access;

class Response
{
    /**
     * The response message.
     *
     * @var string|null
     */
    protected $message;

    /**
     * Create a new response.
     *
     * @param  string|null  $message
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($message = null)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the response message.
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return $this->message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the string representation of the message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string) $this->message();
    }
}
```

how this file miss the rest of methods the laravel docs talk about ??

Comment: Are you certain your laravel version is up to date? Check by running `php artisan -V`

Comment: Also, usually you would use `Response::deny()`, not `Response::authorize()`. Is there any particular reason you do it this way?

Comment: thanks @IGP , this method does not exist in laravel 5 that I'm using

Comment: I tried `Response::deny()` I got the same .. and I thought that  authorize is the currect method not unauthorized error 401

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: You can use booleans instead of `Response::`. `return $user->role === 'admin';` works just as well.

Comment: @matiaslauriti `Laravel 5.8`

Answer (score 0):

tihs method requires **laravel >= 6.x**
this method **not available** in laravel **5**
so make sure the laravel version in your project matches the laravel version that you browsing in laravel docs or in laravel API